# TreeSet duplicates just the first item when importing from file

Tags: java, file, treeset

I have implemented a class called EventSet that contains a TreeSet with a custom comparator. The comparator should be consistent with equals, since it appears TreeSet uses compare or compareTo to do all the needed comparisons before adding an element to the set. My app needs to read a text file with a series of commands and one possible command is to import a text file where events are specified. So an hypothetical event.txt file contains several lines like "IN LOGIN 18082019 ab001 45.457, 9,181 A", the app calls a method that parses the string and converts it in to an Event object, which gets added to the EventSet instance. The prolem here is quite bizzare: everything works fine except if in the command file I try to import the same event.txt file twice the first line of the file gets converted into an Event and inserted in the set as a duplicate even if equals and compare says it's a duplicate. This happens only for the first line of the file no matter how I change it. Here is some of my code so far:

Class EventSet:

```
private static EventSet instance;
private TreeSet<Event> eventTree;

//costruttore
private EventSet() {
    EventComparator comp = new EventComparator();
    this.eventTree = new TreeSet<Event>(comp);
}

public static EventSet getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new EventSet();
    }
    return instance;
}

public TreeSet<Event> getEventTree() {
    return eventTree;
}

public void setEventTree(TreeSet<Event> eventTree) {
    this.eventTree = eventTree;
}


public boolean add(Event e) {
    return this.eventTree.add(e);
}

public boolean add(Set<Event> set) {
    return this.eventTree.addAll(set);
}
```

Class EventComparator:

```
public EventComparator() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
    if(e1.equals(e2)) {
        return 0;
    } else if(e1.getTimestamp().compareTo(e2.getTimestamp())>=0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Class Event:

```
RegState reg_state;
String user_id;
LogState log_state;
Position position;
Date timestamp;
Emotion emotion;

//costruttore
public Event(RegState reg_state, LogState log_state, Date timestamp, String user_id, Position pos, Emotion emo) {
    this.reg_state = reg_state;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.log_state = log_state;
    this.position = pos;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.emotion = emo;
}



public RegState getReg_state() {
    return reg_state;
}



public void setReg_state(RegState reg_state) {
    this.reg_state = reg_state;
}



public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}


public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}


public LogState getLog_state() {
    return log_state;
}


public void setLog_state(LogState log_state) {
    this.log_state = log_state;
}


public Position getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(Position position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public Emotion getEmotion() {
    return emotion;
}

public void setEmotion(Emotion emotion) {
    this.emotion = emotion;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = reg_state.toString()+" | "+log_state.toString()+" | "+InputLine.d_format.format(timestamp)+" | "+user_id+" | "+position.toString()+" | "+emotion.toString();
    return s;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(user_id, reg_state, log_state, position, timestamp, emotion);
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj==null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj instanceof Event) {
        Event e = (Event)obj;
        if (this.user_id.equals(e.getUser_id()) & this.log_state==e.getLog_state() & 
                this.position.equals(e.getPosition()) & this.timestamp.equals(e.getTimestamp()) & this.emotion==e.getEmotion() & this.reg_state==e.getReg_state()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Method that imports cmd.txt file:

```
    void import_cmd() throws NumberFormatException, ParseException {
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;
    String current;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(cmd_path);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        if (this.controller != null) {
            controller.get_message("Error: file not found at this location "+cmd_path.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return;
    }

    InputLine line;

    try {
        current = br.readLine();
        while (current != null) {
            if (this.controller != null) {
                line = new InputLine(current, controller);
            } else {
                line = new InputLine(current);
            }
            if (line.cmd_check() == 1) {
                String extracted = line.getIn_line().substring(line.getIn_line().indexOf("(")+1, line.getIn_line().indexOf(")"));
                String path = this.event_path.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+extracted;

                try {
                    import_events(path);
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("File "+ extracted + " successfully imported ");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Error: file not found at "+path);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Error: unable to read from file at "+path);
                    }
                }
            } else if (line.cmd_check() == 2) {
                boolean valid = line.validate_date_iterval(line.getIn_line());
                if (valid) {
                    //call create map
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Map correctly created for "+ line.getIn_line());
                    }
                } else if (this.controller != null) {
                    controller.get_message("Invalid date at "+ line.getIn_line()+": unable to create map");
                }

            }
            current = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Method that imports event.txt files:

```
private void import_events(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {   

    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br; 
    String current; 
    String[] tokens;


    fr = new FileReader(path);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    current = br.readLine(); 

    if (current == null) {
        if (this.controller != null) {
            controller.get_message("Warning: event file is empty, no events to import");
        }
        br.close(); 
        fr.close(); 
        return; 
        }

    InputLine il;
    while (current != null) { 

        current = current.trim(); 

        if (this.controller != null) {
            il = new InputLine(current, controller);
        } else {
            il = new InputLine(current);
        }

        if (il.line_ok()) { 
            tokens = current.split(Pattern.quote(" "));

            RegState reg_state = RegState.valueOf(tokens[0]); 

            String user_id = tokens[3]; 

            LogState log_state = LogState.valueOf(tokens[1]);


            InputLine.d_format.setLenient(false); 
            Date timestamp = InputLine.d_format.parse(tokens[2]);


              String[] latlong = tokens[4].split(","); 
              double lat = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]); 
              double longi = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]); 
              Position pos = Position.create(lat, longi);

              if (pos == null) { 
                  if (this.controller != null) {
                      controller.get_message("Error: invalid coordinates at "+current+", event ignored");
                  }
                  break; 
              }

              Emotion emotion = Emotion.valueOf(tokens[5]);

              Event event = new Event(reg_state,log_state, timestamp, user_id, pos, emotion);

              boolean added=EventSet.getInstance().add(event); 
              if (this.controller != null) {
                  if (added) {
                      controller.get_message("Event successfully created with "+ current);
                  } else if (!added) {
                      controller.get_message("Duplicated event was ignored at "+ current + ": event already present in the set");
                  }
              }
            }
            current = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close(); 
        fr.close(); 
        return; 
        }
```

The text files I'm using for testing-
cmd.txt

```
import(eventi1.txt)
import(eventi2.txt)
create_map(10062019-12062019)
import(eventi2.txt)
```

eventi2.txt

```
IN LOGIN 10062019 ab00x 45.464,9.191 A
IN LOGIN 10062019 ab002 45.463,9.192 F
IN LOGOUT 10062019 ab001 45.458,9.181 S
OUT LOGOUT 11062019 ab002 45.473,9.173 N
IN LOGIN 11062019 ac003 45.461,9.187 T
IN LOGIN 12062019 ad004 45.464,9.188 T
OUT LOGOUT 12062019 ab001 45.473,9.173 N
```

Some images of the results:
[image]

[image]

Comment: this looks wrong - `else if(e1.getTimestamp().compareTo(e2.getTimestamp())>=0) {return 1;}` - you are returning 1 even if the timestamps are identical.

Comment: Yes, it's intentional, because I can have the same timestamp for 2 different events (if and only if the events are different, meaning for example that everything is equal minus the emotional state)

Comment: but in that case you can have two Events for which compare(e1,e2) and compare(e2,e1) both return 1 (if they are not equal but their timestamps are identical), which violates the Comparator contract. You should return 0 if the timestamps are identical.

Comment: But if the compare method returns 0 the event is considered equal and it's not added to the set, is it correct? If it is it's not what I want. Just to be clear: since the timestamp is in the format ddmmYY, 2 events can happen in the same day of the year provided that they're different for at least one parameter (registration state, log state, user name, coordinates or emotional state). I want both of these events added to the tree

Comment: If you want two events with same timestamp not to be considered identical by the TreeSet, you have to compare other properties of the Event when the timestamps are equal. Otherwise, your compare() method doesn't define a consistent ordering.

Comment: Isn't calling for equals method of the Event class correct in this case? Can you post an example maybe?

Comment: Try to make a minimal example for the problem, please. There is too much code that is not related to the problem. Btw: Your edit did not remove the problem. ```compareTo``` is still inconsistent.

Comment: @Donat I don't understand why though I'm sorry

Comment: @IfLoveWasBornToDie92 please read the Javadoc for ```compareTo``` and you will understand. It makes no sense to repeat it here. The issue is that it makes no difference if ```compareTo``` returns 1 or 2 or any other positive integer value.

Comment: Don't complicate. In `compare()` just do `return e1.getTimestamp().compareTo(e2.getTimestamp())` and nothing else.

Comment: Another thing to look at is immutability of `Event` class (unfortunately it is mutable) and also what it means for 2 events to be equal. Would *timestamp* and *userid* not suffice? Can you have more than 1 event from the same user within the same millisecond type question?

Comment: I've read it, simply put then should I use another data structure if I want 2 different events with same timestamp to be allowed? I initially discarded HashMap and HashSet because they don't mantain order between objects. I was convinced by TreeSet performance also because in the app I need to traverse the tree and keep adding elements in order

Comment: @diginoise you can, but for that I've written the equals method in the Event class directly. You can have 2 events that have the same propreties minus one (they must differ for AT LEAST one of them)

Comment: Your comparator needs to compare all the fields that are compared in equals(). Don't just compare the timestamp. Make timestamp the primary comparison, then if both timestamps are equal, compare the next field, and so on. And don't call equals() in your comparator, just compare.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Could something like this work? (sorry just realized I've called equals, I'll modify it in a second)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException as long as two equal objects return 0 from `compareTo` you are fine. Quote from java doc for `Comparable`:  *The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C*  This does not mean that every 2 objects deemed equivalent according to ordering have to be equal. Just the opposite: every 2 equal objects have to have the same order.

Comment: Here is the code, can this work? public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
  int result = e1.getTimestamp().compareTo(e2.getTimestamp());
  if (result == 0) {
   int comp = e1.getUser_id().compareTo(e2.getUser_id())+ e1.getLog_state().compareTo(e2.getLog_state())+
   +e1.getReg_state().compareTo(e2.getReg_state())+e1.getPosition().compareTo(e2.getPosition())+
   e1.getEmotion().compareTo(e2.getEmotion());
   return comp==0?0:1;
  }
  return result;
  
 }

Comment: @diginoise please read the doc again. Assume e1 and e2 are not equal, but compare(e1, e2) returns 0. Then the sentence "_The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C_" implies that the natural ordering is _not_ consistent with equals, since e1.compareTo(e2) does _not_ have the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you are right! In which case the equality has to be redefined, otherwise the `Set` operations are going to be off here, which can lead to some tricky bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Apparently the issue was caused by calling a method that reads a file and performs the add() to the tree inside another method that reads from file. I edited import_events() and import_cmd() methods and now everything works fine.

```
private HashSet<Event> import_events(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {     

    FileReader fr1;
    BufferedReader br1; 
    String current; 
    String[] tokens;
    HashSet<Event> set = new HashSet<Event>();

    fr1 = new FileReader(path);
    br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1); 
    current = br1.readLine(); 

    if (current == null) {
        if (this.controller != null) {
            controller.get_message("Warning: event file is empty, no events to import");
        }
        br1.close(); 
        fr1.close(); 
        return set; 
        }

    InputLine il;
    while (current != null) { 

        current = current.trim(); 

        if (this.controller != null) {
            il = new InputLine(current, controller);
        } else {
            il = new InputLine(current);
        }

        if (il.line_ok()) { 

            tokens = current.split(Pattern.quote(" "));

            RegState reg_state = RegState.valueOf(tokens[0]); 

            String user_id = tokens[3]; 

            LogState log_state = LogState.valueOf(tokens[1]);



            InputLine.d_format.setLenient(false); 
            Date timestamp = InputLine.d_format.parse(tokens[2]);


              String[] latlong = tokens[4].split(","); 
              double lat = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]); 
              double longi = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]); 
              Position pos = Position.create(lat, longi);

              if (pos == null) { 
                  if (this.controller != null) {
                      controller.get_message("Error: invalid coordinates at "+current+", event ignored");
                  }
                  break; 
              }

              Emotion emotion = Emotion.valueOf(tokens[5]);

              Event event = new Event(reg_state,log_state, timestamp, user_id, pos, emotion);

              set.add(event);
            }
            current = br1.readLine();
        }
        br1.close(); 
        fr1.close(); 
        return set; 
        }
```

Now import_events() returns an HashSet of events contained in the file.

import_cmd() uses the HashSet as a parameter for the call addAll() on the tree.

```
void import_cmd() throws NumberFormatException, ParseException {
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;
    String current;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(cmd_path);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        if (this.controller != null) {
            controller.get_message("Error: file not found at this location "+cmd_path.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return;
    }

    InputLine line;
    Set<Event> toAdd=new HashSet<Event>();

    try {
        current = br.readLine();
        while (current != null) {
            if (this.controller != null) {
                line = new InputLine(current, controller);
            } else {
                line = new InputLine(current);
            }
            if (line.cmd_check() == 1) {
                String extracted = line.getIn_line().substring(line.getIn_line().indexOf("(")+1, line.getIn_line().indexOf(")"));
                String path = this.event_path.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+extracted;

                try {
                    toAdd=import_events(path);
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("File "+ extracted + " successfully imported ");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Error: file not found at "+path);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Error: unable to read from file at "+path);
                    }
                }
                boolean addOk=EventSet.getInstance().add(toAdd);
                if (this.controller!=null) {
                    if (addOk) {
                        controller.get_message("Events added");
                    } else {
                        controller.get_message("No events to add");
                    }
                }
            } else if (line.cmd_check() == 2) {
                boolean valid = line.validate_date_iterval(line.getIn_line());
                if (valid) {
                    Date[] dates = line.convertIntervaltoDates(line.intervalExtract(line.getIn_line()));
                    createmap(dates[0], dates[1]);
                    if (this.controller != null) {
                        controller.get_message("Map correctly created for "+ line.getIn_line());
                    }
                } else if (this.controller != null) {
                    controller.get_message("Invalid date at "+ line.getIn_line()+": unable to create map");
                }

            }
            current = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```